# How can I determine which user scripts are running in Chrome for a website I visit?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, greasemonkey

Using Greasemonkey in Firefox I can see the user scripts that are currently loaded for a website.

Is there a similar tool in Google Chrome?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Greasemetal](http://www.mychromeaddons.com/chrome-addon-greasemetal-greasemonkey-for-chrome/).  Development has been halted as support for Greasemonkey style scripting was installed in Chrome 4. Check out this [discussion](http://dev.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/user-scripts).

Comment: I was unable to determine how to tell if my script is currently running or not in Chrome. I am looking for something similar to clicking on the Greasemonkey Icon and seeing a check next to all currently matching scripts for a site.